# PHP Object Relational Mapping Framework

Tags: php, orm, cakephp, doctrine, kohana

I would like to know which one of the following is the best choice for O/R mapping in PHP:

```
Axon
CakePHP
Doctrine
Kohana PHP
lworm
PdoMap
Propel
Rocks
Qcodo
Redbean
Sphorm
Torpor
```

We are going to use PHP only for Web Service implementation. We have a Java background so a framework which is inspired by Hibernate would be easier for us to use as long as it's a good, well documented and more or less easy to use O/R mapping library.

Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to mention Zend Framework, which IMHO is a worthy candidate !

Comment: The problem is, that you are mixing frameworks with ORM libraries... These are 2 different things IMO. Most of the frameworks allow to exchange their own ORM implementation with other 3rd party libs (Doctrine most of the time)

Comment: I changed the framework to library but framework and library can be used interchangeably in this case. In the end an O/R mapping library provides you the framework for mapping an object-oriented domain model to a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jensgram already notes, it is hard to tell which option suites your needs.

That said, I have experience with Kohanaphp and it's integrated ORM. I must say it works perfect, but it has limited functionality if you compare it to Doctrine2. If you need advanced options like inheritance mapping and proxy classes Doctrine is the way to go. Like Doctrine 2 introduction says:

> Object relational mapper (ORM) for PHP
>   that sits on top of a powerful
>   database abstraction layer (DBAL). One
>   of its key features is the option to
>   write database queries in a
>   proprietary object oriented SQL
>   dialect called Doctrine Query Language
>   (DQL), inspired by **Hibernates HQL**.
>   This provides developers with a
>   powerful alternative to SQL that
>   maintains flexibility without
>   requiring unnecessary code
>   duplication.

As it says, it is inspired on Hibernate HQL. I don't have experience with the other options you mention, so I can't say anything usefull about those.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this question is that it is hard to tell what is the best choice for *your* specific task and environment. Furthermore, a full comparison would require in-depth knowledge of all the alternatives.

As for **Doctrine** you'll be able to find a good piece of [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/en). And it is fairly easy to get going.